# Temp file does not appear in xampp/tmp

Tags: php

I'm uploading a csv file to my php server with this form:

```
<form action="importCSV.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <br>Select file: <input type="file" name="file">
            <br><input type="submit" name="import" value="Import file">
</form>
```

And what I want to do with that file is to add its content to a table in my mysql server.

```
$url=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$con = new mysqli(HOST, US, PW, BBDD);
$sql="load data local infile '" . $url. " into table users fields terminated by ':'";
$con->query($sql);
$con->close();
```

The problem is that in the "tmp" folder of the php server doesn't appear the csv file, but in this line `$url=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` $url has a real url with a tmp_name. I don't understand what's happening there: I have the url with the tmp_name of the file but it actually doesn't exists?

I have checked the php.ini file and this are the values for the file uploads:

```
file_uploads=On
upload_tmp_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"
upload_max_filesize=2M
max_file_uploads=20
```

I'm not worried about the "upload_max_filesize", the file I'm trying to upload has a size of only 56 bytes.

Please, any ideas?

Comment: The uploaded file exists in the tmp folder ONLY until you move it or the script terminates. When the script terminates PHP automatically removes the file from the tmp folder

Comment: So do I have to move it, add to the table and then delete it?

Comment: Are you looking for the file after the script has completed? Or are you saying that the `load data...` query has failed?

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: The `load data` query fails because the file is not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe this...
It seems that the mysql server doesn't understand this character `\`. It's only a problem of compatibility between operative systems.

The solution is only to replace the character: `$url= str_replace("\\", "/", $url)`.